# When I insert new record trigger before updates works

Tags: trigger

Why this trigger change run on saving and change fields?

I want to create the record with some values for first name and LastName and only after update change it to values predefined in the trigger.

```
trigger HelloWorld on Lead (before update) {
    for(Lead l : Trigger.New){
        l.FirstName = 'Hello';
        l.LastName = 'World';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? It's working on every update, as you wrote in your code. What's the problem?

Comment: @sfdcfox This trigger change this field for every new record which I create. I need to create a record with some predefined values -> than save and only after that press edit and change some fied - and on this changes i want to run my trigger.

Comment: If this trigger is applying its logic on insert, most likely you have some other logic somewhere that is triggering an update on it. Alternatively, you could compare the Createddate to the LastModifiedDate (as long as you don't consider migration records insertion, as they can be inserted with a different "CreatedDate" as "now")

Answer (score 1):

Triggers run when the given event occurs. You defined your trigger to run every time an update occurs. Your trigger always overwrites the values regardless as to whether they have values or not.

If you want fixed values only on create then use `before insert`, not `before update`.

However, this is a broken approach since it will always discard entered values on insert (update currently) even through bulk load, or some API (e.g. REST). Better to check see if the field has a value first and only then set this "default").

If you just want default inputs in a new record in the UI, there are mechanisms for that.

However, your question is not clear on what you really want to do so this answer is similarly vague.